# react-native keyboard doesn't hide

Tags: react-native, keyboard, hide

I don't have any input fields on the screen. But after keyboard always shows up.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      Image,
      TouchableHighlight,
      Button,
      ListView
} from 'react-native';
import FloatingActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

Keyboard.dismiss();
```

render function uses ListView and ActionButton.

How to hide keyboard in just this screen in iOS and Android ?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: why do you import { Keyboard } from 'react-native' if you do not use it?

Comment: In one of the example I found, somebody suggested using { Keyboard } from 'react-native' and Keyboard.dismiss();.

Comment: show your render function , then only we will know (all).